# Is there a integrable function non-vanishing a.e. on a semifinite measure space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a semifinite measure space not $\sigma$-finite , is there any way to define a square integrable function not equal to zero almost everywhere?

i have not been able to think on a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: @nicomezi: $L^2$ has no $\sigma$-whatever restrictions.

Comment: May be I am just thinking too much in term of "usual concepts" for this question, which clearly requires something else.

Comment: in fact, i am interested in the case where the measure space is localizable. I have an invertible multiplication operator, $T_{g}$ acting on a $L^2$ space and i want to prove that g is not zero a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously not. If $f\in L^2(\mu)$ then $\mu(\{x:|f(x)|>1/n\}<\infty$, hence  $\{x:f(x)\ne0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

The fact that you say in a comment is what you really want to prove is also trivial. In fact semi-finite is exactly enough. Let's define $$T_gf=fg.$$Then

> > **Lemma.** $\mu$ is semifinite if and only if $g\ne0$ almost everywhere for every $g\in L^\infty$ such that $T_g$ is invertible.

As a big hint, here's a proof of the other direction:

Suppose $g\ne0$ on some set of positive measure. Since $\mu$ is semifinite there exists $E$ with $0<\mu(E)<\infty$ such that $g=0$ on $E$. If $f=\chi_E$ then $f\ne0$ but $T_gf=0$, so $T_g$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for that short answer!. I proved the same direction by using the fact that if $T_{g}$ is invertible, $0$ is not on $\sigma(T_{g})$.  This implies invertibility of $g$ a.e. because the latter is the essential range of $g$. But i prefer your shorter proof .